# JQuery Datepicker with generated DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website that uses JQuery to construct a rather large table.  When I try to select a set of input elements created this way by class and add a datepicker to them, nothing happens.  The table is generated durinng document.ready(); is there a certain time I have to execute $('.date_pick').datepicker(); in order for this to work?  If not, what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you could provide the relevant code, it would be helpful. But basically, you should be able to assign `datepicker()` to the appropriate elements once they are inserted into the DOM.

Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/ojoye)** of attaching the datepicker to inputs in a table that is inserted into the DOM through jQuery. Tested in Firefox 3.5 and IE 6.

Answer (score 0):

Without code, you'll need to debug this on your own. Couple of guidelines:

- If you're using JQuery, use JQuery's built in function rather than document.ready()
- Are you sure you're declaring the datepickers **after** the table is generated?
- Make sure the input elements don't have the same IDs, give them the same classname, then do something like.

  $('.dateInputs').datePicker();