# Datepicker JQuery on JavaScript generated fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, user-interface, datepicker

I'm adding a date picker to dynamically generated fields.

```
('#addScnt1').live('click', function() {
$('<p class="textocampodetexto" style="margin-left:20px; margin-top:20px;"> 
<label for="p_scnts1">  <input id="au_fechainicioperiodo2" 
name="au_fechainicioperiodo2" type="text" size="7"  
value="" /> </p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
```

Those fields are added when I click an 'Add Field' button.

The date picker doesn't appear when I click on the generated field. I know the datepicker is working because I put the code outside the javascript code and it works.

How can I achieve this then?

Comment: Where do you call .datepicker()?

Comment: Please see this answer in order to help yourself with it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396536/jquery-datepicker-with-generated-dom-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to reattach the datepicker to your input field.

Try the solution found here: [Why does jQuery UI's datepicker break with a dynamic DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059107/why-does-jquery-uis-datepicker-break-with-a-dynamic-dom)

The code isn't identical to yours but if you could extract the input field from your selector you could do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work like this ( [LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/utadaz/4) ):

```
$(function () 
{
  $('#addScnt1').click(function() {

    $('<p class="textocampodetexto" style="margin-left:20px; margin-top:20px;"><label for="p_scnts1">  <input id="au_fechainicioperiodo2" name="au_fechainicioperiodo2" type="text" size="7" value="" /> </p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    $('#au_fechainicioperiodo2').datepicker(
    {
        showOn: "both",
        dateFormat: "dd M yy",
        firstDay: 1, 
        changeFirstDay: false
    });
  });
});
```

(**NOTE**: I'm supposing that the variable `scntDiv` is defined with an DOM object before this call)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#addScnt1').live('click', function() {
    var newElement = $('all your html'); //then append it wherever

    newElement.find('.input-selector').datepicker();
});
```